# In app billing not working: RESULT_ERROR

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I was testing the in app billing and all worked great. Now, when I send a purchase request, I have the "buy window", and when i click to "buy now", the GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION send me a RESULT_ERROR response code :/ Same thing when I try to restore transactions, it fails.

Is there any way of know if the problem is mine or google's? And what is it ^^
(I took the google's code code and just implementing the folowing class)

```
private class ThemePurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
    public ThemePurchaseObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(PageAccueilActivity.this, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingSupported(boolean supported) {
        Log.d("ThemePurchaseObserver", "onBillingSupported: "+supported);

        if (supported){
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Utils.getPrefFile(), MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean restorationDone = prefs.getBoolean(KEY_PREF_RESTORATION_DONE, false);
            if (!restorationDone){
                mBillingService.restoreTransactions();
            }
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState,String itemId, int quantity, long purchaseTime,String developerPayload) {
        Log.d("ThemePurchaseObserver", "onPurchaseStateChange()");

        if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED){
            Log.d("ThemePurchaseObserver", itemId+ "PURCHASED");
        } else if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.REFUNDED){
            Log.d("ThemePurchaseObserver", itemId+ "REFUNDED");
        } else if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.CANCELED){
            Log.d("ThemePurchaseObserver", itemId+ "CANCELED");
        } else {
            Log.d("ThemePurchaseObserver", itemId+ " unknow state");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(RequestPurchase request, ResponseCode responseCode) {
        Log.d("ThemePurchaseObserver", "onRequestPurchaseResponse: "+responseCode);         
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreTransactionsResponse(RestoreTransactions request, ResponseCode responseCode) {
        Log.d("ThemePurchaseObserver", "onRestoreTransactionsResponse: "+responseCode);

        if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK){
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Utils.getPrefFile(), MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editeur = prefs.edit();
            editeur.putBoolean(KEY_PREF_RESTORATION_DONE, true);
            editeur.commit();
        } else {

        }
    }       
}
```

And there are the logcat for the restoration:

```
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): Billing service connected
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): CheckBillingSupported
INFO/BillingService(3363): CheckBillingSupported response code: RESULT_OK
DEBUG/ThemePurchaseObserver(3363): onBillingSupported: true
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): RestoreTransactions
ERROR/BillingService(3363): restoreTransactions received RESULT_OK
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): request id: 8836359618243990524
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): request id: -1
INFO/BillingService(3363): handleCommand() action:com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): RestoreTransactions: RESULT_ERROR
DEBUG/ThemePurchaseObserver(3363): onRestoreTransactionsResponse: RESULT_ERROR
```

the logcat for a static purchase ("android.test.purchase"):

```
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): RequestPurchase
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): request id: 8990314669027459189
INFO/BillingReceiver(3363): notifyId: android.test.purchased
INFO/BillingService(3363): handleCommand() action: com.example.dungeons.GET_PURCHASE_INFORMATION
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): GetPurchaseInformation
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): request id: 7301564145243038858
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): RequestPurchase: RESULT_OK
DEBUG/ThemePurchaseObserver(3363): onRequestPurchaseResponse: RESULT_OK
INFO/BillingService(3363): handleCommand() action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
DEBUG/BillingService(3363): GetPurchaseInformation: RESULT_ERROR
```

I tried to use an other google account of my phone (after reset it to factory settings), but now it give me an RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE when I check if it's supported...

Comment: check the market app version of your phone. Second you could check if you have the required permissions. Thirdly have you followed all the steps mentioned in the billing document by Google

Comment: the app version is 2.3.6 so it's ok, the permissions are ok, and I think I done all I needed to do :/
plus, before getting RESULT_ERROR every time, all worked good.

Comment: well..... now it works....I just update my youtube and google maps apps.... what's the link? --'

Answer (score 0):

I also had this, the way it got solved was after when I opened android market app and accepted terms and conditions with new account.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it gives me this error when testing for extensive periods of time.  I think the Market detects excessive usage and shuts itself off for requests for a time. Try again in 24 hours or try testing using a different Google account.